# How to increase efficiency of comparing elements of a list?

Tags: python, list, data-structures, constraints, time-complexity

Whenever I code on online platforms and somehow I have to compare the elements of a list to one another, I use the following code which according to me is the most efficient possible. This is the last code which I was practicing. It was to find the maximum index between 2 same elements.

```
max=0
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    if max==(len(mylist)-1):
        break
    for j in range(i + 1, len(mylist)):
        if mylist[i] == mylist[j]:
            if max>(abs(i-j)):
                max=abs(i-j)
```

It runs most of the test cases, but sometimes it shows "time limit exceeded." I know it is related to the constraints and time complexity but I still can't find a better way. If anyone could help me, that would be great.

Comment: I guess we can omit the inner loop if we know the `#do something`. For example, if it's an element-wise operation on one list, we can remove the second loop. I think it depends on the body of the second loop. Please provide more information.

Comment: Could you share the problem text (or the *URL*)? *Do something* is kind of important. As a hint, you could use `collections.Counter`.

Comment: Seems odd to use `abs(i-j)` when you know that `i > j` in all cases. Why not just `j-i`, and eliminate the call to `abs`?

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to use C based functions in Python. Also don't name variables python types like `list`.

```
x = [item for i, item in enumerate(l) if item in l[i+1:]]
# do something with list of values
```

Answer (score 0):

You could group by equal elements and then find the difference in-group, and keep the maximum:

```
lst = [1, 3, 5, 3, 7, 8, 9, 1]

groups = {}
for i, v in enumerate(lst):
    groups.setdefault(v, []).append(i)

result = max(max(group) - min(group) for group in groups.values())

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
7
```

The complexity of this approach is `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_longest_distance_between_same_elements_in_list(mylist):

    positions = dict()
    longest_distance = 0

    if len(mylist) < 1:
        return longest_distance

    for index in range(0, len(mylist)):
        if mylist[index] in positions:
            positions[mylist[index]].append(index)
        else:
            positions[mylist[index]] = [index]

    for key, value in positions.items():
        if len(value) > 1 and longest_distance < value[len(value)-1] - value[0]:
            longest_distance = value[len(value)-1] - value[0]

    return longest_distance


l1 = [1, 3, 5, 3, 7, 8, 9, 1]
l2 = [9]
l3 = []
l4 = [4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
l5 = [10, 10, 3, 4, 5, 4, 10, 56, 4]
print(get_longest_distance_between_same_elements_in_list(l1))
print(get_longest_distance_between_same_elements_in_list(l2))
print(get_longest_distance_between_same_elements_in_list(l3))
print(get_longest_distance_between_same_elements_in_list(l4))
print(get_longest_distance_between_same_elements_in_list(l5))
```

Output -

```
7                                                                                                                                                                                  
0                                                                                                                                                                                  
0                                                                                                                                                                                  
4                                                                                                                                                                                  
6
```

Time Complexity : O(n)